# Methods called by the up button in android

Tags: android

What methods are called by the up button in android? I'm referring to the button created by defining a parent activity in the manifest.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. To improve your chances of getting an answer, see the Help page, [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also refer to [How to Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Google - Providing Up Navigation](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html) you can handle up button click inside on ***onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)*** something like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
    case android.R.id.home:
        // Home/Up button clicked
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Note that if you define a parent activity in the manifest, overriding this callback is generally unnecessary.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice on this google link, they say that you must override onOptionsItemSelectd. Check it out: https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html